# For loop in Swig template engine

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I'm using [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) as a template engine for Express.js and I found no way to make a for loop with a variable like so:

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
  //whatever
}
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

As posted on your [github issue for the same question](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/issues/528), loops like this don't exist in Swig. You can iterate over actual objects and arrays, however. (See [for-tag documentation](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/tags/#for)).

Otherwise, you could create a range helper, as discussed [here](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/issues/497)

```
swig.setDefaults({ locals: {
  range: function (start, len) {
    return (new Array(len)).join().split(',').map(function (n, idx) { return idx + start; });
  }
}});
```